# rails validation to check length of integer and show message if false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm dealing with a phone **number field**, so i require it to be present

> presence: true

alias

> presence: {message: "Number is requred"}

and also I want it's **length to be 10**. so I did

presence: {message: "Number is requred"} , length: {is: 10}

Now I want that **if the number entered is not 10 digit,then a message should be displayed.** I tried this:

> presence: {message: "Number is requred"} , length: {is: 10, message: "Number must be 10 digit long."}

But it's not working. How should I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked

```
validates_length_of :number, is: 10,  message: "Number must be 10 digit long"
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think `is` can only be used when validating the length of a string, and not a number.

Answer (score 7):

try with a regular expression , something like this:

```
validates_format_of :phone, :with => /[0-9]{9}/
```

being {9} the number of digits you want to validate

Answer (score 0):

validates_format_of :phone, :with => /[0-9]{10}/ ,:message => "Contact should be 10 digit number"
this will work for both 10 digit, number